# How can I add multiple events in services.yml file as event Listeners in Doctrine symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using this:

```
my.listener:
        class: Acme\SearchBundle\Listener\SearchIndexer
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

Now if I try to listen for two events like this:

```
- { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist, preUpdate }
```

it gives an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need an event subscriber instead of an event listener.

You'd change the service tag to `doctrine.event_subscriber`, and your class should implement `Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber`.  You need to define a `getSubscribedEvents` to satisfy `EventSubscriber` which returns an array of events you want to subscribe to.

ex

```
<?php

namespace Company\YourBundle\Listener;

use Doctrine\Common\EventArgs;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;

class YourListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array('prePersist', 'onFlush');
    }

    public function prePersist(EventArgs $args)
    {

    }

    public function onFlush(EventArgs $args)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this in services.yml and again same error `{ name: octrine.event_subscriber, event: prePersist,preUpdate }`

Comment: *d*octrine (typo?), and don't specify the events in your configuration.  `getSubscribedEvents` does that.  Also, what is the error?

Comment: thanks for that i tried this and it worked  `{{name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default}}`. Also can i add more events in the subscribed event array like postFlush and more. or does it takes only two

Comment: Take note that using Doctrine Subscriber is less performant than using Listener:

See https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-listeners

"Symfony loads (and instantiates) Doctrine listeners only when the related Doctrine event is actually fired; whereas Doctrine subscribers are always loaded (and instantiated) by Symfony, making them less performant."

Answer (score 24):

I think you can do like this:

```
my.listener:
        class: Acme\SearchBundle\Listener\SearchIndexer
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

Comment: Yes, you can do it like this. It looks very simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

**Lifecycle subscribers are deprecated starting from Symfony 6.3.
So you can use this :**

```
Acme\SearchBundle\Listener\SearchIndexer:
        tags:
            -
                {
                  name: 'doctrine.event_listener',
                
                  # this is the only required option for the lifecycle listener tag
                  event: 'postPersist',
                  
                  # listeners can define their priority in case multiple subscribers or listeners are associated
                  # to the same event (default priority = 0; higher numbers = listener is run earlier)
                  priority: 500,

                  # you can also restrict listeners to a specific Doctrine connection
                  connection: 'default'
                }
                
            -   {
                  name: 'doctrine.event_listener',
                
                  # this is the only required option for the lifecycle listener tag
                  event: 'postUpdate',
                  
                  # listeners can define their priority in case multiple subscribers or listeners are associated
                  # to the same event (default priority = 0; higher numbers = listener is run earlier)
                  priority: 500,

                  # you can also restrict listeners to a specific Doctrine connection
                  connection: 'default'
                }
```